# Delete from table if checkbox not checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have Users, Roles, and Permissions.

When creating/editing a Role, you can choose which permissions are enabled by checking their checkbox which will save the Permission in a table called 'roles_permissions' (basically on permissions that are allowed are stored in the join table).

So my edit role method is as follows:

```
def edit
  @role = Role.find(params[:id])
  @permissions_by_controller = Permission.order('controller asc').group_by(&:controller)
end
```

and the update method (the patch):

```
def update
  @role = Role.find(params[:id])
  if @role.update_attributes(role_params)
    redirect_to roles_path, :notice => 'Article updated!'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

and the params:

```
def role_params
  params.require(:role).permit(:name, permission_ids: [])
end
```

In the edit view I have a checkbox like so:

```
<%= check_box_tag "role[permission_ids][]", permission.id, @role.permissions.include?(permission), :id => permission.id, :class => 'switch__checkbox' %>
```

This works fine for when I check the checkbox and it saves.

However when I uncheck the checkbox and save, it doesn't remove the permission... presumably becuase no param is passed back. How do I solve this?

The associations are set as:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'users_roles'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions, :join_table => 'roles_permissions'
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => 'roles_permissions'
end
```

Note: I've also noticed that Roles cannot be removed from a User in the same way as it uses checkboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classic problem. `f.check_box` solves this for you, by returning `false` when unchecked, but `check_box_tag` does not.

You can solve it with a hidden field with an empty value just before the tag.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "role[permission_ids][]", '' %>
<%= check_box_tag "role[permission_ids][]", permission.id...
```

The form knows to populate the empty value field when nothing is selected. (If it's clearer for you, you can also put `'false'` instead of an empty string.)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing steel's answer (and since I can't comment on his answer bc of my rep)
I'll say to anyone looking for a different way to solve this.

I prefer attaching the hidden_field to the form .

```html
<%= form.hidden_field :permission_ids, { multiple: true, value: '' } %>
```

Since we are calling `form.hidden_field`, the name and id will already contain `role` and it will add `permissions_ids` as a key inside role.
Multiple will add the needed square brackets.

The resulting html tag will be:

```html
<input multiple="multiple" value="" type="hidden" name="role[permission_ids][]" id="role_permission_ids">
```